# How should I handle calls-to-action on all items in a list?

Tags: lists, call-to-action

I have a long list of items with an obvious CTA for each one. The content of the items in the list are different but the CTAs are all the same. This is not in an application context, more a marketing/research context.

My concern is that the list looks very repetitive so the CTA doesn't stand out. Is there any advice out there on how to promote conversion on a list?

My initial thought was display the CTA on hover over the item as that's the best indication I have for 'selection' of something on the list but I don't know if everyone is as prone to highlighting stuff they're interested in as me!!

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a mockup?

Comment: Edited to add mockup

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use hover to display CTA's, users don't know what they can do until they hover over each item.

Also it sounds like it could be a list with checkboxes on the side and all CTA's at the top of the list:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcwlaW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not in an application context, more marketing. I've added a mockup to the original post to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: +1 for no hovers. First, you'll have to add a cue that users should hover to get more options. Second, there's no hover on touchscreens.

Comment: @jdbann - Knowing that you are not in an application context would be very valuable information to know and should be further explained in your question. Sort of like background information.  That way people can answer your question within the context of what you _are_ in. =D

Comment: @CodeMaverick First time on here! I'll more explicitly state it in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently designing a very similar list interface and can totally emphasise with you.
What I'm doing is that I have given a rather generic, non-attention seeking color to the buttons in the list (a light shade of blue in my case) but when the user hovers over the item, i change it to a brighter CTA style color (orangish yellow for me).
The reason for doing this was to use the obvious benefits of the hover effect and brighter colours in attracting attention but still informing users who don't tend to explore much that there is an action (button press) which they can perform.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hover - is not a good solution here, because it hides the info on what user can do with items. It decreases the [affordance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance).

You should ask yourself the following questions:
1) Will user be doing this operation very often? 
2) How many items users are going to "button" during one session?
If many, then you probably should use Igor-G solution - a) user selects items to operate on, b) perform the action on them

And the repetition shouldn't scare you - because you only have one CTA for every item.

Answer (score 0):

> My concern is that the list looks very repetitive so the CTA doesn't
>   stand out. Is there any advice out there on how to promote conversion
>   on a list?

This feels really really subjective. The context behind your list - what does it contain, what's your target audience, what does the call-to-action lead to etc. etc. - without such specifics, it is very difficult to suggest the best UX for conversion gain.

For e.g. here's a list of books on Amazon.

[image]

Notice there's no call to action (buy button) on the list. Instead important properties about the items (cost /reviews etc.) are eye catching and then anyone interested in a single item on that list will drill down, go through details and will be shown a pronounced CTA on that details page, followed by the flow to convert. Adding a buy button on this list is probably more clutter than value, even though that's what Amazon wants the end users to eventually do, ain't it.

Anyway, this was just a line of thought that I wanted to share. Beyond this, if your list in context needs the CTA button, then do not worry about repetition. It's all about the aesthetics then.

- Ensuring the UI doesn't feel very cluttered; is well spaced
- CTA button ain't unidentifiebly away from the item info
- The UI doesn't feel too boxy due to plenty of dark borders all around

Without knowing the specific nature of your list, one can really comment on just UI, more than UX.